# Fire an event with Decentraland SDK

Tags: typescript, decentraland, decentraland-ecs

I'm trying to fire a custom event in my Decentraland scene. [According with the docs](https://docs.decentraland.org/creator/development-guide/custom-events/#emit-events), I just need to do something like:

```js
const events = new EventManager()
events.fireEvent(new MyEvent(field1, field2))
```

So, following that example I'm trying to simulate the `E` user input when users click on a `UIImage`. To accomplish that:

1. I setted the onClick property of the button like this:

```js
let btn = new UIImage(someContainer, new Texture('assets/images/btn.png'))
btn.onClick = () => { triggerPrimaryInput() }
```

2. The `triggerPrimaryInput` function is like:

```js
triggerPrimaryInput()
{
    const simulatedEvent: LocalActionButtonEvent = {
        origin: new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        direction: new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        button: ActionButton.PRIMARY,
        buttonId: 1,
        type: 1
    }

    const em = new EventManager
    em.fireEvent(simulatedEvent)
}
```

3. When I do a click on the button, Chrome console shows the error:

```
Error: Error: The EventConstructor is not registered
```

Because of that, I created a new class using the `@EventConstructor()` decorator and I put the `triggerPrimaryInput()` function's logic in the constructor, but the error keeps the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, debuging Decentraland's `Input.ts` I finally solve my problem. I just needed to do:

```js
// Create the button and set the onClick property
let btn = new UIImage(someContainer, new Texture('assets/images/btn.png'))
btn.onClick = () => { triggerPrimaryInput() }

function triggerPrimaryInput()
{
    // Define the input event
    const simulatedEvent: LocalActionButtonEvent = {
        origin: new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        direction: new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        button: ActionButton.PRIMARY,
        buttonId: 1,
        type: 1
    }

    // Call this method using the simulated event
    Input.instance.handlePointerEvent(simulatedEvent)
}
```

With that, I can simulate the `E` keyboard input when the user clic over a button.
Using this strategy I was able to create a custom UI allowing the user to interact with an NPC avoiding the use of the dialogs provided by [NPC-Utils](https://github.com/decentraland/decentraland-npc-utils)